# Accessing a contentplaceholder on a master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to access a content placeholder from Site.Master.cs code-behind. I tried the following:

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.FindControl("MainContent");
```

and

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
```

But it gives me an error and when I tried debugging and this.Controls has objects but not "MainContent"

How can I access the master page placeholder controls?

Comment: You're using the code behind of the master page that has the CPH? Then just do `MainContent` without using `FindControl`.

Comment: That worked. thanks! Why don't you put it as an answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `ContentPlaceHolder` is in the markup and the code behind you're modifying is for the same page, you can access it directly.

```
var cph = MainContent;
```

Of course, probably no need to assign it to a variable since it's already in scope.

```
MainContent.Visible = false;
```